# Does Terraform support Azure deployment slots?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

It is possible to use Terraform to create an azure app service with a deployment slot for staging and production. Am trying to deploy a open source project master branch to staging slot and Release branch to production slot. But Terraform App Service (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html) doesn't yet support deployment slots?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/provision-infrastructure-using-azure-deployment-slots

Comment: Have you seen https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service_slot.html ?

Comment: Thanks, Let me check that one.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment mentioned, the Terraform indeed supports deployment slots via [azurerm_app_service_slot](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service_slot.html). Please note that

> Note: When using Slots - the app_settings, connection_string and
> site_config blocks on the azurerm_app_service resource will be
> overwritten when promoting a Slot using the
> azurerm_app_service_active_slot resource.

For more information, you could read the [Tutorial: Provision infrastructure with Azure deployment slots using Terraform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/provision-infrastructure-using-azure-deployment-slots). The article illustrates an example use of deployment slots by walking you through the deployment of two apps via GitHub and Azure. One app is hosted in a production slot. The second app is hosted in a staging slot.